# Чтение чата minecraft

Tags: python, логирование, ос, чат, minecraft

Я хотел бы написать программу, которая считывала бы сообщение определенного игрока в чате minecraft, а затем что-нибудь с ним делала и выводила результат на экран.

Я нашел в интернете код, позволяющий считывать сообщения в чате:

```py
import time, os
    
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line
                
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        logfile = open(os.getenv("APPDATA")+"/.minecraft/logs/latest.log", "r")
        loglines = follow(logfile)
        for line in loglines:
            if "[CHAT] <Nikita>" in line:
                print (line)
                print (len(line))
```

Но возникла следующая проблема:

- когда игрок Nikita пишет сообщение, выполняется только `print (line)`, а `print (len(line))` выполняется только после того, как игрок Nikita напишет еще одно сообщение;
- когда игрок Nikita пишет свое сообщение второй раз, выводится `len(line)` для первого сообщения и `print (line)` второго сообщения и так далее.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: Почему именно python? Bukkit/Spigot API был бы гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Дело в том, что это не мой сервер minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузил твой код у себя. Использую Python 3.9.
Все работает...

```
import os
import time


def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logfile = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + "/.minecraft/logs/latest.log", "r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        if "[CHAT] <Nikita>" in line:
            print(line.strip("\n"), "  |||  ", len(line))
```